# How can I allow sql to set datetime with subsonic

Tags: c#, sql, linq, activerecord, subsonic

I have begun using SubSonic and I am wondering how to get it to ignore DateTime properties on insert. I am using the ActiveRecord template and have default methods to create the datetime properties on insert on the DB side.

When I try to insert I get the following: 
    SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

I would rather not have to set the datetime in code as all items will drop into a queue and I'd like their created on datetime to be the actual time the record was created. Is there any way to get this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the BeforeInsert() and BeforeUpdate() methods (Tested and confirmed) with SubSonic 2 and set the Columns you want to ReadOnly.

```
public partial class Products
{
    protected override void BeforeInsert()
    {
        Schema.GetColumn(Columns.CreatedOn).IsReadOnly = true;
        base.BeforeInsert();
        Schema.GetColumn(Columns.CreatedOn).IsReadOnly = false;
    }

    protected override void BeforeUpdate()
    {
        Schema.GetColumn(Columns.ModifiedOn).IsReadOnly = true;
        base.BeforeUpdate();
        Schema.GetColumn(Columns.ModifiedOn).IsReadOnly = false;
    }
}
```

Schema is static so you can do this once in your code (even from outside the class) and don't worry about it again but I would prefer this way.

I haven't tried this with SubSonic3 but the IsReadOnly Property is still there so it should work, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the SubSonic ORM for .NET - you might try asking this question on the [SubSonic support blog](http://blog.wekeroad.com/subsonic/subsonic-support/) or send and email to subsonicproject@googlegroups.com requesting help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define DateTime as parameter. The similar situation is described here - http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/?p=2982#first.